# how I can install a package. deb without internet connection in the terminal?

Tags: installation, command-line

I have no internet connection and I can install the packages. Deb that I downloaded from internet that are older versions but I can not install anything and not as the terminal

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! what happens when you double click the .deb file? does the ubuntu software center launch?

Comment: You might want to use the [Keryx](http://keryxproject.org/) utility for installing packages and keeping your system up to date, if it is not connected to the Internet.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way I know to install a local deb file is to run the following command:

`sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb`

from a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Double clicking the deb package is the easiest way to install with no terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Before going for a install please make sure that you have required dependencies with you.Also install those dependencies .